# How to fill an image in a dynamc size button in Tkinter

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter

This is my first post, so I hope I do not do anything wrong.

Objective:

My objective is to make a menu with 4 buttons. This frame should show only those 4 buttons. All buttons must fit into the dynamic frame.

This is the main program:

```
class Tab_View(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):

        self.frame_ini = tk.Frame(self.parent, bg=bg_1)
        self.frame_ini.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        self.btn1= tk.Button(self.frame_ini, image=self.image_button1, cursor="hand2")
        self.btn2= tk.Button(self.frame_ini, image=self.image_button2, cursor="hand2")
        self.btn3= tk.Button(self.frame_ini, image=self.image_button3, cursor="hand2")
        self.btn4= tk.Button(self.frame_ini, image=self.image_button4, cursor="hand2")

       # Putting all the buttons in the frame
        self.btn1.pack(expand = True, fill='both')
        self.btn2.pack(expand = True, fill='both')
        self.btn3.pack(expand = True, fill='both')
        self.btn4.pack(expand = True, fill='both')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.minsize(900,400)
    frame(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This shows all buttons in the Frame, but the problem in that the images attached to buttons appear to be smaller than buttons themselves.

I have tried with `resize` but when I maximize the frame, these pictures are not updated so they don't fit.

I am expecting this:
(https://i.gyazo.com/c52fbda518594ceec0ec1cebe0baedd7.png)

But the images must change the size according with the screen size.
Could you please advise me about a better solution?

Thank you all! 
I hope I have expressed myself well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this using only Tkinter, as far as I know. Either you will have to write a custom image button which uses a image library that can scale images (like Pillow) or you can try to find a GUI library which provides scalable image buttons.